# fetch FormData method with multiple text and image file

Tags: reactjs, forms, fetch-api

I'm being fighting this for a couple of days without good results.

Am I using the FormData method wrong? is the formData.append right? I do have another form to perform a "PUT" with a JSON.stringify method on it than works like a charm. I don't know what's happening here.

here is the error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://tiendeo-frontend-cards-api.herokuapp.com/cards' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

here is the code:

```
const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('title', title)
    formData.append('description', description)
    formData.append('image', selectedFile)

    console.log(selectedFile)
    console.log(title)
    console.log(description)

    fetch('myendpoint', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json",
                    "Autorization": "Bearer mybearer token",
                    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"},
        body: formData
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then ((res) => {
        console.log('Enviao!!', res)
        window.location.reload()
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('ERROR JODER!', error)
    }) 
}
```

so many thanks in advance

Comment: Is the server deployed in heroku is written by you ? . Because it looks like we have CORS issue .

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are in development mode and is because of the policy of calling the http request from your localhost to the server. you can pass it in development mode thru the below methods:

1. using the browser extensions like https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf
2. config your custom proxy thru https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

Comment: Its an Heroku deployed, swagger documented, ExpressJS I suppose backend. Developed by the company I'm trying to solve the technical interview...

Comment: have you tried to add header parameter Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in api call?
 headers: { "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*", ...}

Comment: Thankyou. Yes, I used that header and nothing happened. The CORS still persists...